# Class Load trace has Multiple entries of [Loaded GregorSamsa from __JVM_DefineClass__] causing Perm gen Out Of memory

Tags: java, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, permgen

When do we get below line in out console ? Multiple entries of below class results in PermGen OutOfMemory issue. 
    [Loaded GregorSamsa from **JVM_DefineClass**]

This is on Weblogic 10.3.x
  java version "1.6.0_26"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)

Comment: Can you give more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were able to get trace of [Loaded GregorSamsa from JVM_DefineClass]

We opened a JMX port for our application and monitored it via visualvm. It showed GregorSamsa class is loaded every time we have a

```
<x:transform>
```

tag called from any our jsp. Which is actually a XSLT transform to create xls file.

It loads GregorSamsa class every time this jsp is triggered and said tag is executed. It resulted in quick fill up of Perm Gen space. removing JVM param  of -xnoclassgc helped us unload the unwanted classes and reduce perm gen space.